# Imprimir apenas a coluna de uma matriz

Tags: python

Sou iniciante no python e estou com dúvidas quanto à utilização de list e tuple e seus operadores. Estou tentando imprimir apenas a coluna de uma matriz porém não estou conseguindo. Já tentei fazer o seguinte para imprimir a segunda coluna:

```
matriz = [[1, 5], 
          [7, 4], 
          [8, 3]]

print matriz[0:3][1]
```

Porém ele está imprimindo apenas a segunda linha, como se estivesse `print matriz[1]` apenas. O `[0:3]` não indica que ele deve percorrer todas as linhas e o `[1]` que deve imprimir a segunda coluna? Gostaria de saber como funcionam esses operadores. Também já vi em outros códigos utilizando algo do tipo `matriz[0, 1]` ao invés de `matriz[0][1]`, entretanto se eu não separo as linhas das colunas com colchetes, meu programa dá erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é isso que essa expressão faz. `lista[inicio:fim]` cria uma **sublista** iniciada (inclusivamente) em `inicio` e terminada (exclusivamente) em `fim`:

```
>>> [0,1,2,3,4,5][1:4]
[1, 2, 3]

>>> [0,1,2][0:3]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Note que nesse segundo exemplo a lista foi a mesma (pois você começou no seu início e foi até o seu fim. Da mesma forma, no seu código a sublista retornada está sendo igual à matriz original, e ao acessar o seu segundo elemento você está pegando de fato a segunda linha:

```
>>> matriz = [[1,5],
...           [7,4],
...           [8,3]]
>>> matriz[0:3]
[[1, 5], [7, 4], [8, 3]]
>>> matriz[0:3][1]
[7, 4]
```

Se você quiser o segundo elemento de cada linha da matriz, você pode usar uma compreensão de listas:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in matriz]
[5, 4, 3]
```

Aí é só acrescentar um loop para imprimi-los um a um:

```
>>> for v in [x[1] for x in matriz]:
...     print v
...
5
4
3
```

(embora nesse caso é besteira fazer isso, bastaria iterar sobre a lista original e imprimir `v[1]`...)

A propósito, se em vez de uma lista você tiver um objeto, você pode usar outros objetos complexos (como tuplas) como chaves. Nesse caso faria sentido algo como `matriz[0, 1]`, mas ele estaria acessando uma propriedade específica do objeto e não dois valores distintos de uma lista aninhada:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x[1, 2] = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

>>> x = {}
>>> x[1, 2] = 10
>>> x
{(1, 2): 10}
```

Mas se o que você possui são listas de listas, de fato é necessário dois usos dos colchetes para acessar um elemento interno, não se pode (infelizmente...) usar tuplas como índices.

---

Nota: se for *extremamente necessário*, você poderia colocar o `print` dentro da própria compreensão de listas, evitando um loop. No Python 3 pelo menos, não sei se dá pra fazer isso no Python 2:

```
>>> [print(x[1]) for x in matriz]
5
4
3
[None, None, None]
```

(essa última linha é a lista criada, onde cada elemento é o retorno do `print` - `None`; normalmente ela será ignorada)

Apenas tenha o cuidado que isso cria uma nova lista, do mesmo tamanho da original (1º nível), o que eleva o consumo de memória. Essa técnica somente seria recomendada caso você estivesse num contexto em que só cabe uma expressão (dentro de um `lambda`, por exemplo) e - por concisão - você quisesse evitar a criação de uma nova função.

Comment: O exemplo do print é bastante *sujo*. Porque criar uma lista com vários objetos None? Enquanto uma compreensão de lista funciona bem aplicando outra função, no caso do print não faz sentido algum, sendo mais gambiarra e preguiça de escrever duas linhas em vez de uma.

Comment: @PabloPalácios Várias linguagens possuem um "for-each" que permite aplicar uma função a uma coleção em uma única expressão (ex.: JavaScript - `matriz.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e[1]); })`). Python não possui tal *built-in*, então sim, é uma gambiarra... A pergunta que se precisa fazer é se essa gambiarra é útil/necessária ou não. Como você faria por exemplo se precisasse incluir esse loop dentro de um lambda?

Comment: Qual loop você se refere? Meu ponto é, se o objetivo é fazer simplesmente um print, um for tradicional é mais adequado. Não faz sentido gerar uma lista (ou qualquer objeto) se posteriormente ela não será usada, ainda mais de objetos None.

Comment: @PabloPalácios Eu entendi, o meu ponto é que se você precisa fazer tal operação em um contexto em que se espera somente uma expressão -  e não um conjunto de instruções (*statements*) - você não consegue. O fato de existir um meio de se fazer isso, mesmo gambiarrado, é algo que aumenta a expressividade da linguagem. Mas é lógico que se você estiver num contexto em que se espera uma instrução, o melhor é optar pela clareza, como você sugere (e nesse caso eu não usaria compreensão de lista alguma, só um `for` onde se o `print` usa `x[1]`).

Comment: Saquei, mas enquanto esse contexto não for o da questão, não colocaria esse tipo de exemplo onde alguém com pouca experiência pode simplesmente copiar e colar fora de contexto. Imagina se o OP tiver uma lista gigante, no fim disso ele acaba com duas listas gigantes podendo obter problemas com isso.

Comment: @PabloPalácios Tem razão! Editei a resposta movendo esse trecho pro final e explicando melhor sua finalidade e limitações.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine que sua matriz seja uma tabela e você tenha um axis: x e y:

```
     0 1
   .-----> x
0  | 1 5
1  | 7 4
2  | 8 3
   V
   y
```

Se você quer acessar a posição `7  (x=>0,y=>1)`. Basta fazer isso através dos índices:

```
matriz[1][0];
```

Que em tese seria algo representado por:

```
 matriz[y][x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Para trabalhar com matrizes, é legal usar numpy.

Com ele você pode fazer:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 5], [7, 4], [8, 3]])
>>> print a.transpose()[0]
[1 7 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Salve André você quer algo como isto:

```
>>> matriz = [[1, 5], 
...           [7, 4], 
...           [8, 3]]
>>> for m in matriz:
...     print m[1]
... 
5
4
3
>>>
```

Caso queira a primeira coluna basta mudar m[0]